# Propagating angular attribute directives during compilation of element directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm struggling with writing a custom element directive. The directive, let's call it `myElement`, produces multiple `textarea` or `input` fields depending on some parameters and applies `ngModel`s to those fields.

I also want to be able to specify other attribute directives on `myElement`, such as `ngMaxlength`, which get propagated to the dynamically generated inputs.

Example:

```
<my-element foo="bar" ng-maxlength="100" my-other-directive/>
```

Could be compiled as:

```
<my-element foo="bar">
    <input type="text" ng-model="bar[abc]" ng-maxlength="100" my-other-directive/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="bar[xyz]" ng-maxlength="100" my-other-directive/>
</my-element>
```

I also set the priority of `myElement` to a higher value. But although the attributes are correctly removed from the parent element, the other directives, like `my-other-directive` in the above example, still get executed for the `myElement` element. This results in an exception being thrown for directives which require `ngModel`. What can I do to prevent that?

**EDIT** I'm using angular 1.2.20

**EDIT 2** My directive looks like this:

```
restrict: 'E',
compile: function (element, attrs) {
    var inputElements, attrsToRemove = [];
    inputElements = ... // Create inputs based on attrs ...
    angular.forEach(attrs.$attr, function (originalName, normalizedName) {
        inputElements.attr(originalName, attrs[normalizedName]);
            attrsToRemove.push(originalName);
        }
    });
    angular.forEach(attrsToRemove, function (name) {
        element.removeAttr(name);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is something like this `<my-element foo="bar" my-child-directives="ng-maxlength='100' my-other-directive"/>` a valid option for you? The idea is to pass a string with the directives you want to include in the child elements instead of defining them directly on the parent.

Comment: @bmleite You're a genius! Why didn't I think of that? Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

priority applies to same element, [angularjstutorial.appspot.com/learn/directive#priority](http://angularjstutorial.appspot.com/learn/directive#priority)

terminal stops lower directives from compiling, [angularjstutorial.appspot.com/learn/directive#terminal](http://angularjstutorial.appspot.com/learn/directive#terminal)

suggesting to use require (^) and a controller,   [angularjstutorial.appspot.com/learn/directive.html#/_tblcontents_23](http://angularjstutorial.appspot.com/learn/directive.html#/_tblcontents_23)

see also, [angularjstutorial.appspot.com/learn/directive#/sync-existing](http://angularjstutorial.appspot.com/learn/directive#/sync-existing) (scope {'='})
and [angularjstutorial.appspot.com/learn/directive#sync-attribute](http://angularjstutorial.appspot.com/learn/directive#sync-attribute) (scope {'@'}

Comment: linked ngtutorial.com resources are broken; answer is stale